# Unable to SFTP Bitnami (Wordpress) Google Cloud Instance

Tags: wordpress, sftp, google-compute-engine, bitnami, filezilla

I'm trying to SFTP Compute Engine from MAC using Filezilla. I can SSH with port 22 without any problem. But I need R/W/D access to my files and trying SFTP to port 21 and getting the following error,

```
Command:    keyfile "/bitnami-google-api-project-4xxxxxxxxxx.pem"
Command:    open "bitnami@104.xxx.xxx.xxx" 21
Error:      Connection refused
Error:      Could not connect to server
```

I referred a couple of similar threads here nothing make this work, sofar I did,

1. Bitnami Key added in Google Compute Engine and both are same Added.
2. PEM key file (MAC) in FileZilla settings.
3. I'm using root password with default username

Anything I'm missing from the doc to follow to get access through 21?

Answer (score 0):

SFTP runs over an SSH session, usually on TCP port 22. In the Bitnami Stack SFTP is configured to use port 22. In the link below you will find information about how to upload files using SFTP using Bitnami Cloud Images on Google Cloud:

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#how-to-upload-files-to-the-server-with-sftp

If you want to use SFTP on any other port, you need to open that port on your server and configure SFTP to use port 21. You can open a port on your server following the steps described in the guide below:

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#how-to-open-the-server-ports-for-remote-access

Comment: I have already opened port 21 in GCE firewall for my specific IP and PEM files added in Fileziall client.

Comment: Still no luck, Is there any direction that I can troubleshoot?